# NPM - how to avoid setting npm config every time you open bash

Tags: node.js, bash, npm

I have set up the proxy in npm with these two commands:

```
>npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.[Company Name].com:8080                                                                   
>npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.[Company Name].com:8080
```

And that worked fine for the time I had bash opened.
But, when I closed bash, and opened it again, I had to do the same thing one more time, since npm config didn't have the proxy set.
How can I set the npm config so that it stays set even after the bash is closed?

Comment: Set a global NPM config file? Add it to your bash profile?

Answer (score 0):

You can set npm configurations in user config file `~/.npmrc` like below.

```
proxy=http://user:passsword@host.domain.com:8080/
https-proxy=http://user:passsword@host.domain.com:8080/
strict-ssl=false
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

OR you can set the above configurations globally in the below path.

```
$PREFIX/etc/npmrc
```

[Source](https://docs.npmjs.com/configuring-npm/npmrc.html)